# How can I prevent duplicate data storage in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

I have information about a car:

```
brand="bmw"
model = "h256"
miles = "22.35 mils"
year = 2017
price= "$22.35"
```

I want to save this information in mysql database.
So if this information does not exist in the database, it is stored.

But I have a problem when inserting.
I know that not exists should be used. But I do not know how to use not exists.
Help me please.

The code I have in mind:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO mydata VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%i","%s") IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mydata)'%(brand,model,miles,year,price))
```

At the top, I wrote the code I wanted, but that code is wrong.

I have searched for this many times. But I did not find a clear answer.
Help me please . for solving this problem

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't store 'mils' or '$'

Comment: And I don't really understand what problem it is that you think you need to solve. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good search term to use here is:

> mysql insert if not exists

This will give several solutions. [Here's a good example.](https://itecsoftware.com/insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql#:%7E:text=Insert%20only%20if%20that%20record%20does%20not%20already,insert%20it%20if%20the%20record%20does%20not%20exist.)

One of my favorite solutions based on the link is something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO mydata ([HEADER NAMES])
SELECT '%s','%s','%s','%i','%s'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from mydata where [primary key] = '%s')
```

Comment: Which means the question is a duplicate and should be closed as such, not answered again and again.

Comment: @Shadow No, the link I provided is off-site. If I was aware of a duplicate, I definitely would have VTC it as one.